# Every ribbon graph can be embedded into an oriented surface such that its cyclic orderings are induced from the orientation of the surface.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I have trying to understand the proof of the lemma ([Page 14, Lemma: 2.2.4](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf)) which is stated as follows:

Every ribbon graph can be embedded into an oriented surface
such that its cyclic orderings are induced from the orientation of the surface.

I have the following confusions:

1. In the first paragraph, it is written that : for every vertex $v$ define a subset $U_v \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|E_v|$ (the geometric realization of the star of $v$, see  definition 2.2.2) $\textbf{boundary components}$
   labelled by the elements of $E_v$ of the form depicted in Figure 2.6 (Only the
   straight lines of the boundary are part of the surface.)

In the above context I have the following figure.

[image]

What are the boundary components here? Are the red lines boundary components labelled by the elements of $E_v$? As written in the first braket. only the red lines are the part of surfaces

2. In the second paragraph, it is written  that: Similarly we attach to each edge $e$ a strip $V_e$ as depicted in Figure 2.7
   whose two boundary components (again only the straight lines are part of
   the surface) are labelled by $e_+$ and $e_-$.

[image]

So, in the following figure, which are the boundary components lebelled by $e_+$ and $e_-$? Also, it is written that "again only the straight lines are part of the surface". Which straight lines are only the part of surface in this case?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first answer (2): $e_-$ and $e_+$ are the two horizontal dotted sides. By convention you can take the bottom one to be $e^+$ and the top $e_-$. Do a simple example: look at the ribbon graph with 2 vertices $v$, $w$ and just one edge $e=\{v,w\}$. Represent the vertices as closed disks. The boundary of these disks has an orientation, for example counter-clockwise, which has to be the same for all vertices. Now take the edge $e$ represented as a ribbon and attach it to these disks. For the orientation to make sense, this ribbon must have one horizontal side oriented towards $v$ and the other horizontal side must be oriented away from $v$. These are your $e_-$ and $e_+$.

Regarding (1) and boundary components: Pick a vertex and an edge. Trace the outgoing arrow out of the edge until you return to where you started from. The path that you traced is one boundary component. To find a different boundary component you would pick a different vertex-edge pair that hasn't already been traced. When you trace out all the vertices and edges, you are done.

The simple example from above of two vertices and one edge has just one boundary component. For a more elaborate example, take a triangle represented as a ribbon graph. You will have 2 boundary components, the "inner" and the "outer" sides of the ribbons.

---

The definition that you're working with is very formal and very difficult and obsucres what otherwise is a relatively simple concept. I think that you would benefit by understanding first a simpler approach.

An orientable cellularly embedded graph (which is equivalent to a ribbon graph) is a graph $G$ embedded (drawn) on an orientable closed surface $X$ such that $X\setminus G$ is a disjoint union of topological disks. This means that

(i) vertices are points on the surface,

(ii) edges are curved segments between vertices,

(iii) crossings happen only at the vertices and

(iv) $X\setminus G=F_1\cup\dots\cup F_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ and each $F_i$ is homeomorphic to an open disk. The sets $F_i$ are called the *faces* of $G$ (to be more precise, the faces of a particular embedding of $G$).

Let $G$ be cellularly embedded on $X$. We can represent this embedding as follows: let $e=\{v,w\}$. To each edge assign two labels called half-edges in the following way: if you're standing on the vertex $v$ and looking towards $w$ along $e$, then on the left side of $e$ (where left is defined by the orientation of your surface) place a label $i$. And if you're standing on the vertex $w$ and looking towards $v$ along $e$, place a label $j$ on the left side.

In this way you have represented an edge $e$ as a pair of half-edges $i$ and $j$.  This is written as the transposition $(i~j)$. Hence every edge is represented by such a transposition. Now each vertex can be represented by a permutation cycle $(i_1~\cdots i_k)$ which you obtain just by reading the half-edges incident to it in a preferred order (e.g. counter-clockwise).

So what does this have to do with your questions? The $e_-$ and $e_+$ correspond to the half edges $(i~j)$ that we are using to represent an edge. Hence in (2) the $e_-$ and $e_+$ can also be considered as the two vertical dotted sides of an edge which you glue to a vertex (represented as a disk) so that the orientation makes sense. The boundary components are identified with the faces $F_i$ which can be read simply by reading the labels inside a particular face (and if you've done your labeling according to the convention that I've described before, you should have the same number of labels in a face as there are edges bordering it).

Now to obtain a ribbon graph from a cellularly embedded graph, you "inflate" the vertices into closed disks and edges into ribbons and remove the faces. Conversely, to obtain a cellularly embedded graph from a ribbon graph, you glue in the faces, contract the disks into points and ribbons into curved segments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have one confusion regarding $(1)$. What are the boundary components in my first figure?

Comment: The boundary components are what you get by tracing the red dashed lines in your figure along the directions given by the arrows. Presumably there's more to that surface than what's shown, so you would need the complete picture to trace the components in full.

Comment: Thanks for your four previous answer. I have one more confusion. In the paragraph you have explained about an orientable cellularly embedded graph or a ribbon graph.  But I cannot understand what we mean by "crossings happen only at the vertices". is that mean that edges may cross, over or under?

Comment: @user1138886 that means that the edges can't intersect at any point except at the vertices. For example, you can embed $K_5$ as a cellular graph on the sphere because it is non-planar, so there would be a pair of edges that intersect at a point that is not a vertex. But on a torus this intersection can be resolved so you can embed it cellularly.

Comment: In the answer you have defined the faces of the ribbon graph as follows: $X\setminus G=F_1\cup\dots\cup F_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ and each $F_i$ is homeomorphic to an open disk. The sets $F_i$ are called the *faces* of $G$. Now is it true that each oriented edge is contained in a unique face?

Comment: Do the following figure has $5$ faces?

Comment: In the definition that I gave there are no oriented edges. The role of oriented edges is played by half-edges, and it is true that each half-edge is contained in a unique face, namely that half-edge whose label belongs to the face.

Comment: Can you please write that why it is true?